# Overlaying Map QGIS 3 (oblique secant cylindrical projection)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, mapping

I am trying to overlay a heightmap of Canada (EPSG:3857) with an old map scan I have (https://geoscan.nrcan.gc.ca/starweb/geoscan/servlet.starweb?path=geoscan/fulle.web&search1=R=294063).

The projection of the scan I have come to find is an **oblique secant cylindrical projection**, and I am hoping to reproject the heightmap to this projection so everything aligns properly.

I was wondering how I would go about doing this with QGIS3? I have looked into using the Georeferencer Add-on, or using gdalwarp but I think I am confused as to what an oblique secant cylindrical projection is and how to define it. I have tested a few of the cylindrical projections in QGIS but nothing seemed to align properly.

Comment: You're better off trying to warp or georeference the old map to 3857. The 1906 map predates well-known geoCRS (datums) and, while I didin't dig into it, there's no ellipsoid listed. There are probably no projection parameters. The closest projection would be oblique mercator, but we don't even know if the map used a conformal or equal area projection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would it be possible to georeference the old 1906 map, save the custom CRS and apply this to the heightmap? I'm not sure what transformation method would be best though, perhaps thin-plate? I'd really like to keep the dimensions of the old map and warp the heightmap to fit.

Comment: When you georeference, you'll be linking points in the old map to current data in whatever coordinate reference system you want. Once you're happy with the georeferencing, the 1906 data will be in that target coordinate reference system. You could try directly to 3857, for instance.but the fit might not be very good (aka a lot of warping).

Comment: Yeah the problem is I want to warp the heightmap to the old map not the other way around if that makes sense